# Why it says "lateinit property resendToken has not been initialized" for jetpack compose project?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have phone authentication project in android jetpack compose, so I can do it in my code and I am success to get OTP code from firebase, but I want to use resend code again in my project, so when I click this line of code;

```
 .clickable { modelAuthentication.resendCode(phoneNumberOTP)}
```

it is throw an error like "lateinit property resendToken has not been initialized", I am not get it what I missed, any idea?

**Phone.kt:**

```
@Composable
fun PhoneScreen(

    navController: NavController,
    modelAuthentication: AuthenticationViewModel

    ) {
 val phoneNumberState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }


        OutlinedTextField(
            value = phoneNumberState.value,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = white,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                focusedLabelColor = Grey,
                unfocusedLabelColor = Grey,
                cursorColor = color,
                textColor = color,

                ),
            onValueChange = { phoneNumberState.value = it },
            label = { Text(text = "Phone Number") },
            placeholder = { Text(text = "Phone Number") },
            singleLine = true,
        
   
        )
      Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(285.dp)
                    .height(55.dp)

                ,
                onClick = {
                    modelAuthentication.send(phoneNumberState.value)
                  
             
                },
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    backgroundColor = color
                ),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(40),
               

            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "send",
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 18.sp,
                        color = white,


                        )

                )
            }
```

**PhoneVerify.kt**

```
@Composable
fun PhoneVerifyScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    modelAuthentication: AuthenticationViewModel,
   
) {
    lateinit var resendToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val phoneNumberPatientOTP = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
   
    val context = LocalContext.current
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        println("found activity? ${context.findActivity()}")
        val activity = context.findActivity() ?: return@LaunchedEffect
        modelAuthentication.setActivity(activity)
    }


    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

            OutlinedTextField(
                value = phoneNumberOTP.value,
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    backgroundColor = white,
                    focusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = Grey,
                    focusedLabelColor = Grey,
                    unfocusedLabelColor = Grey,
                    cursorColor = color,
                    textColor = color,

                    ),
                onValueChange = { phoneNumberOTP.value = it },
                label = { Text(text = "Verify code") },
                placeholder = { Text(text = "Verify code") },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.8f),

                )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(7.dp))

        Row(
            Modifier
                .width(300.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,

            ) {

            Text(
                "Resend Code",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(20.dp)
                    .clickable {
                        
                        modelAuthentication.resendCode(phoneNumberOTP)


                    }
                ,
                textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                color = color
            )
        } }
```

**ViewModel.kt**

```
    @HiltViewModel
    class AuthenticationViewModel @Inject constructor(
    
        private val auth: FirebaseAuth
    
        ) : ViewModel() {
    
        lateinit var otp: String
    
        var verificationOtp = ""
        var popNotification = mutableStateOf<Event<String>?>(null)
    
        private lateinit var baseBuilder: PhoneAuthOptions.Builder
    
        fun setActivity(activity: Activity) {
            baseBuilder = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth).setActivity(activity)
        }
    
        lateinit var resendToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
    
      val mCallBack =  object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
override fun onVerificationCompleted(p0: PhoneAuthCredential) {
    handledException(customMessage = "Verification Completed")

}

override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {
    handledException(customMessage = "Verification Failed")

}

override fun onCodeSent(otp: String, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
    super.onCodeSent(otp, p1)
    verificationOtp = otp
    resendToken = p1
    handledException(customMessage = "Otp Send Successfully")
}}

fun sendVerificationCode(mobileNum: String) {
    val options = baseBuilder
        .setPhoneNumber(mobileNum)
        .setTimeout(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .setCallbacks(mCallBack)
        .build()
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
}
    
    
        fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(otp: String) {
            val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationOtp, otp)
            auth.currentUser?.linkWithCredential(credential)
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        handledException(customMessage = "Verification Successful")
    
                    } else {
                        handledException(customMessage =  "Wrong Otp")
    
                    }
                }
        }
    
    
        
    
        private fun handledException(exception: Exception? = null, customMessage: String = "") {
            exception?.printStackTrace()
            val errorMsg = exception?.message ?: ""
            val message = if (customMessage.isEmpty()) {
                errorMsg
            } else {
          

      "$customMessage: $errorMsg"
        }
        popNotification.value = Event(message)
    }


    }
```

Comment: Check the callback. Is that token received before calling  resendCode function?

Comment: @Gobu CSG I'm really dont understand, what is problem

Comment: You're getting error on the viewmodel right.

Comment: yes but in both I getting error, I am not understand why, how can I arrange code correcly?

Comment: Replace your callback on the send function .setCallbacks(callbacks).
You're using couple of callbacks.

Comment: @GobuCSG, I update question but still not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245920/discussion-between-gobu-csg-and-huma33).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your viewmodel looks like this

1 Define the callback on the top

```
val mCallBack =  object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
override fun onVerificationCompleted(p0: PhoneAuthCredential) {
    handledException(customMessage = "Verification Completed")

}

override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {
    handledException(customMessage = "Verification Failed")

}

override fun onCodeSent(otp: String, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
    super.onCodeSent(otp, p1)
    verificationOtp = otp
    resendToken = p1
    handledException(customMessage = "Otp Send Successfully")
}}
```

2 Update the send function

```
fun sendVerificationCode(mobileNum: String) {
    val options = baseBuilder
        .setPhoneNumber(mobileNum)
        .setTimeout(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .setCallbacks(mCallBack)
        .build()
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
}
```

3 Remove the resend function

Note: p1 parameter is the Resend token

If you want resend verification, call the same function (sendVerificationCode)

Comment: tnx for ur answer appreciated, but what I will write here `modelAuthentication.resendCode(phoneNumberOTP)`, becasue for send I am using `modelAuthentication.send(phono.value)` but it is throw error for `modelAuthentication.resendCode(phoneNumberOTP)` as mismatch phoneNumberOTP

Comment: I don't see difference between both functions... When you're calling modified just pass the phone number that's it.

Comment: I update question for both screen how I am using model in screen, it work for send, but it is not work for resend, why?

Comment: In the send function you haven't assigned the resendToken value from the callback code sent function

Comment: I update it again, still same, I guess ı missed somethings

Answer (score -1):

This, in your `ViewModel`

```
lateinit var resendToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
```

is a variable that *hasn't been initialised to a value*. You're not usually allowed to do that - you have to initialise it with something - but the `lateinit` keyword allows you to initialise it *later*. You're making a promise that you'll set a value on it *before* something tries to read that value. The error message you're getting, that `resendToken has not been initialized` means you've broken that promise!

You're initialising it in one of your callbacks:

```
override fun onCodeSent(
    verificationId: String,
    token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken,
) {
    ...
    resendToken = token
}
```

but the problem is this is running *after* you've tried to use `resendToken` in the `resendCode` function, which you call when you click the button. You need a value for `resendToken` before you can do this:

```
.setForceResendingToken(resendToken)
```

---

That's just a general explanation of the problem - I haven't used the Firebase stuff you're working with, so I can't tell you the best way to fix it. But you're calling that `PhoneAuthOptions` builder with a token you don't have yet, which is returned by the `callbacks` you're also providing to that builder. To me, that implies you have to be able to do the `verifyPhoneNumber` call *without* a token, since that's the only way you get one?

So maybe make `resendToken` nullable instead of `lateinit`, and check if it's null before adding it to the builder:

```
var resendToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken? = null

fun resendCode(mobileNum: MutableState<String>) {
    val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth).apply {
        setPhoneNumber(mobileNum.toString())
        setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        setCallbacks(callbacks)
        // only set this on the builder if we have it!
        resendToken?.let { setForceResendingToken(it) }
    }.build()
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
}
```

(I'm assuming the builder methods return the same `Builder` instance so we can just call `apply` on it and the code is neater.) I don't know if that actually works, but I'm just giving you ideas for stuff to try

Comment: The variable assigned in resendCode function. Actually he need to assign from the send function the codesent function returning verificationId and token. He missed to add there. Once he modified in send function it'll work.

Comment: tnx so much for ur answer but it is not work still, ı update queation again

Comment: @GobuCSG the only place `resendToken` **was** being assigned was in that `callbacks` object, in the `onCodeSent` function. The OP's edited the question and now it's not being assigned anywhere at all